# How to add custom validation to EF core model entity type?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework Core v3.1.19 and have begun looking into how I can add custom validation to individual model properties to a database first schema and seem to have hit a brick wall with it all. I discovered the MetadataType attribute which I have tried with a buddy class but that doesn't work. I notice the validation doesn't seem to trigger at all even if I use Fluent API via IsRequired so is I guess out-of-the-box validation is limited to Database Schema constraints.

Is there anyway of attaching a validation handler to a property on the entity model type which is executed before the record is saved using my own validation logic?

There seems very little documentation with regards to this or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: You can override `SaveChanges` and validate properties by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like that is a bit elegant solution but always depend on approach to immutable entities but is good for example. You can use private setters and change values in public methods like `Cancel()` and others. But essense is the same.

Usage example

```cs
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Document doc = new Document();
        
        doc.MyField = "Foo"; // length < 10 as validator accepts
        Console.WriteLine(doc.MyField); // Foo
        
        doc.MyField = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"; // length > 10 as validator should not accept
        // throws FluentValidation.ValidationException: Validation failed
    }
}
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;

using FluentValidation;

    public class Document
    {
        private Document()
        {
        }

        private string _myField;

        public string MyField
        {
            get => _myField;
            set => OnPropertyChange(value, nameof(_myField));
        }

        private void OnPropertyChange(object value, [CallerMemberName] string caller = default)
        {
            var memberwiseClone = (Document)this.MemberwiseClone();
            var field = typeof(Document).GetField(caller, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            field.SetValue(memberwiseClone, value);
            new Validator().ValidateAndThrow(memberwiseClone);
            field.SetValue(this, value);
        }

        private class Validator : AbstractValidator<Document>
        {
            public Validator()
            {
                // validate that MyField's length is less than 10
                RuleFor(d => d.MyField)
                    .Must(m => m.Length < 10);
            }
        }
    }
```

Package for validation is [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentValidation).

Upd: example with base class

```cs
public abstract class BaseEntity<T>
{
    protected AbstractValidator<T> Validator;

    protected void OnPropertyChange(object value, [CallerMemberName] string caller = default)
    {
        var memberwiseClone = (T)this.MemberwiseClone();
        var field = typeof(T).GetField(caller, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        field.SetValue(memberwiseClone, value);
        Validator.ValidateAndThrow(memberwiseClone);
        field.SetValue(this, value);
    }
}

public class Document : BaseEntity<Document>
{
    public Document()
    {
        Validator = new DocumentValidator();
    }
    

    private string _myField;

    public string MyField
    {
        get => _myField;
        set => OnPropertyChange(value, nameof(_myField));
    }


    protected class DocumentValidator : AbstractValidator<Document>
    {
        public DocumentValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(d => d.MyField)
                .Must(m => m.Length < 10);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, I also found the FluentValidation package that should allow me to create the validators and configure them. I'll then hook something into the SaveChanges method to initiate the Validate method on each changed entity.